Transfer simulation outputs as starting values for another simulation
I'm working on simulating a transient system. To achieve this, I must run the simulation with constant parameters (fluid flow) until it reaches a steady state. After that, I manually input these values for each parameter in the transient model. Is there a method to automatically transfer the value of variables from the steady state analysis into the transient analysis as initial values ?
I made an attempt to duplicate the information seen in https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/11787.
failing to succeed,
I selected the file for the starting equation system instead of the initialization technique, but it didn't work.
open modelica version :
Connected to OpenModelica v1.14.1 (64-bit)
Connected to OMSimulator v2.1.0-dev-147-g36ec2c7-mingw
package version : 3.2.3

You can try to generate some CSV file with your desired inputs after steady state is reached, e.g. with the Python scripting API. Then use simulation flag -csvInput (https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/simulationflags.html#simflag-csvinput) to use that one. But to be honest I never got the flag to work for me.
You can open a bug report or feature request on our GitHub: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues
PS: That's a really old version of OpenModelica.

i Just need to delay the use the thermal inertia ( masse component) for a couple of seconds but there is no way to do that because the C  (cp * m) is a constant during the simulation.
do you think of any way to to this without the needing to do a steady state analysis ?
any ways thanks for the response

Then just simulate for a few seconds and then create the input CSV file from the simulation result file.

i'm sorry i'm a new user i search the command you give me but i don't understand how to use it, where should i put the command ? do ou have anu exemple ?
thank you for your answer

Let's look at an example with the classic Lotka Volterra example. We want to simulate the population of foxes and rabbits for 10 time units and then start a new simulation with the start values being the previous simulation result.
LotkaVolterra.mo
model LotkaVolterra
  parameter Real g_r =0.04 "Natural growth rate for rabbits";
  parameter Real d_rf=0.0005 "Death rate of rabbits due to foxes";
  parameter Real d_f =0.09 "Natural deathrate for foxes";
  parameter Real g_fr=0.1 "Efficency in growing foxes from rabbits";
  Real rabbits(start=700) "Rabbits,(R) with start population 700";
  Real foxes(start=10) "Foxes,(F) with start population 10";
equation
  der(rabbits) = g_r*rabbits - d_rf*rabbits*foxes;
  der(foxes) = g_fr*d_rf*rabbits*foxes -d_f*foxes;
end LotkaVolterra;

First we simulate LotkaVoltera for 10.0 seconds:
loadFile("LotkaVolterra.mo"); getErrorString();

simulate(LotkaVolterra, stopTime = 10.0);
val(rabbits, 10.0);   // 1004.1042956221384
val(foxes, 10.0);     // 6.1928347062092755

And write the resulting values of ``rabbitsandfoxes` into a CSV file:
inputs.csv
time, rabbits_0, foxes_0
0.0, 1004.1042956221384, 6.1928347062092755
10.0, 1004.1042956221384, 6.1928347062092755

The second row is needed to make the values constant over time.
Now let's modify our original model to use inputs as start values for foxes and rabbits:
LotkaVolterraWithInput.mo
model LotkaVolterraWithInput
  parameter Real g_r =0.04 "Natural growth rate for rabbits";
  parameter Real d_rf=0.0005 "Death rate of rabbits due to foxes";
  parameter Real d_f =0.09 "Natural deathrate for foxes";
  parameter Real g_fr=0.1 "Efficency in growing foxes from rabbits";
  input Real rabbits_0;
  input Real foxes_0;
  Real rabbits "Rabbits,(R) with start population rabbits_0";
  Real foxes "Foxes,(F) with start population foxes_0";
initial equation
  rabbits = rabbits_0;
  foxes = foxes_0;
equation
  der(rabbits) = g_r*rabbits - d_rf*rabbits*foxes;
  der(foxes) = g_fr*d_rf*rabbits*foxes -d_f*foxes;
end LotkaVolterraWithInput;

and run the simulation with additional simulation flag -csvInput=inputs.csv:
loadFile("LotkaVolterraWithInput.mo"); getErrorString();
simulate(LotkaVolterraWithInput, startTime=10.0, stopTime = 100.0, simflags="-csvInput=inputs.csv"); getErrorString();


I used the OpenModelica ScriptingAPI to simulate the models. You can also use OMEdit to do this. Simulation flags can be added in the Simulation Setup->Simulation Flags->Additional Simulation Flags (Optional):.

To verify everything works as expected compare the results to LotkaVoltera simulated up to stopTime=100.0.
